# Flagging: Allow to issue automated comment

Tags: feature-request

I'm sometimes just browsing "newest questions" and everytime I see problematic questions I'm going to flag these (e.g. off-topic, unclear what you asking).

I think there should be an option (similar to the "Recommend for Deletion" when reviewing "Low Quality Posts") so that the reason should be added as a comment to the post so that the OP knows that this post is seen to be off-topic by at least one user.

This could help to improve further questions and understanding by posters.

Answer (score 2):

On face value, it might get some questions edited/improved before even reaching the actual on hold stage.

Although, the main issue with this is when a user *inaccurately* flags a question, the questioner might be trying to fix something that isn't broken.
They might change what was a good question, delete their question, or come to Meta and ask about it all.

Whereas now the questioner is only notified if community agrees and the required quota of users flags/votes is met, and while not perfect, this is usually accurately and signifies that the on-hold reason is valid.

A notification/message before community voting is unanimous also adds "noise" to the question, and as it's not determined the comment is valid, then not only is it potentially unjustified and pointless noise, but also users will just learn to ignore it until "*the real on hold message appears*".

So I don't think this will add much value or help get questions improved.

Comment: I tend to say two things : recently registered users are usually the target of flagging (and downvotes). And, **accumulating downvotes is as deadly as accumulating flaggings.** - I think that, to better help new user **quickly understand** the right way of asking questions and answering ***is*** to notify them what's wrong with their post. This include downvotes - while that's outside the scope of OP's question. Goal : improve poster's responsiveness, allowing them to correct what was wrong, reducing the avalanche of downvotes and flagging, preventing them from having rants towards SO.

Comment: And, why not - if this is implemented - allow users to flag or upvote that automatic _flag comment_ ? A high number of flags on a _flag comment_ would mean the post wasn't accurately flagged. (and IMHO Upvoting or Flagging _flag comment_ should not affect reputation)

Comment: I think you'd be targeting users who do not care. They have plenty of information before asking a question. Many users ask, get an answer, and close their question, so they don't care about messages or warnings or even downvotes. As there's only me active in this question ATM, perhaps wait for other opinions. I'm not arguing with you, I just don't think it's worth a lot of dev work and adding an entire new area to the site which users will have to learn about. If you are this confident it will work, you should improve your proposal to show more benefits and reasons in favour of it.